# Why does outline' color looks lighter?

Tags: plotting, legending, marker

I have been spending one hour but couldn't figure out this. 
 Why aren't the color of outlines around the markers same with the lines'colors (it loosk lighter)? 
 How can I make them be same?

[image]

```
PointLegend[{Red, Blue, Green}, {"A", "B", "C"}, Joined -> True,
 LegendMarkers -> 
  MapThread[
   ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#1, {Offset[6], 
      0}, {EdgeForm[#2], FaceForm[White]}] &, {{"DownTriangle", 
     "SevenPointedStar", "FourPointedStar"}, {Red, Blue, Green}}],
 LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}, 
 LegendLayout -> (Column[
     Row[{Grid[##, Spacings -> {1, -1}, 
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}]}] & /@ Partition[#, 3], 
     Spacings -> -1.5] &)]
```

Comment: Use ``EdgeForm[{#2, Opacity[1]}]`` instead of ``EdgeForm[#2]``.

Comment: @Domen thanks bro, I can sleep now.

Comment: @Domen - Great catch.  Enter that as an answer.  I'll definitely vote it up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a default base style for markers which gets applied when creating a legend, and it happens to include opacity:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle

(* EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]] *)
```

Therefore, you have to manually set the opacity to 1:

```
PointLegend[{Red}, {"A"}, Joined -> True, 
 LegendMarkers -> {ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][
    "DownTriangle", {Offset[6], 0}, {EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Red}], 
     FaceForm[White]}]}, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}]
```

[image: Legend]

Alternatively, you can remove the opacity from the base style:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = {}
```